# How to validate username and password against wso2 esb Primary User Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working with wso2esb 4.8.1. I wish to authenticate my client against wso2 esb Primary user store with Plain text password.So i have done below changes and its working fine.
I have commented the **PasswordDigest** element.

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
            <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
           <!-- <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property> -->
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
```

and wrote the proxy like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="authent" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="username" value="admin" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="password" value="admin" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <dblookup>
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <dsName>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dsName>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql>select  UM_USER_NAME  from UM_USER where UM_USER_NAME=? and UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?</sql>
                    <parameter value="faisal" type="CHAR"/>
                    <parameter value="faisal" type="CHAR"/>
                    <result name="IsUserExisted" column="UM_USER_NAME"/>
                </statement>
            </dblookup>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="IsUserExisted" expression="get-property('IsUserExisted')"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

I created **faisal** user in my console. So its working fine.
whenever my offset is 0 that time its working fine.If i change the offset its not working.
Its returning null.
Basically i wish to use this query as my username and password validation.

So please let me know what is the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If i change offset also its working for same server not for others

Comment: Your problem is not clear for me, are you saying when you change the server offset in the carbon.xml to something other than 0, this does not work ? 
How many servers do you have, what is the JDBC database you are pointing here ?

Comment: No its not a offset problem.How to validate against JDBC/WSo2Carbon data source using above query with Plain text username password.What i have done above its working in my local system but not in Dev system or any other.Even i compared two servers files but didn't find any change

Comment: If i copy the same server in another machine even this functionality working fine.Whereas i start with new server its not working in same version also 4.8.1